# QMenu::addAction does not work when called inside a specific if-clause

Tags: qt, symbian, qmenu

I encountered a very strange problem:

```
if( currentWidgetType_m == WidgetTypesMap ) {
      qDebug() << "Here we are!";
      optionsMenu_mp->addAction( tr( "Change visibility" ),
         this, SLOT( VisibleItemClicked() ) );

      optionsMenu_mp->addSeparator();
}

optionsMenu_mp->addAction( tr( "Change statistics" ),
      this, SLOT( StatisticsItemClicked() ) );
optionsMenu_mp->addAction( tr( "Change view" ),
      this, SLOT( ViewItemClicked() ) );
```

The condition is **true** in this case and the debug message shows in the output, but the *"Change visibility"* action does not appear in the menu.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Best regards

Comment: Strange !! Have you tried creating a QAction and adding it ?

Comment: addAction returns a new QAction or null? Does the action get added when you move that code outside the if? Does it get added when you remove the addSeparator() call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the QMenu not updating. I solved the problem by recreating the QAction that held the QMenu.